# firebaserecycleradapter() in firebaserecycleradapter cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

The same error keeps coming up. I'm guessing they changed how it works now but since I'm a noob, I really need help fixing it.

```java
    private void loadMenu() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>
            (Category.class, R.layout.menu_item, MenuViewHolder.class, category) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getNama());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //get Category Id and Send to new Activity
                        Intent foodlist = new Intent(Home.this, FoodList.class);
                        foodlist.putExtra("CategoryId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodlist);
                    }
                });
            }
```

"(Category.class, R.layout.menu_item, MenuViewHolder.class, category)" This line is in red and it states that FirebaseRecyclerAdapter() in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to (a bunch of code here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` binds a `Query` to a RecyclerView. When data is added, removed, or changed these updates are automatically applied to your UI in real time.

First, configure the adapter by building `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                        .setQuery(category, Category.class)
                        .build();
```

Next create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` object. You should already have a ViewHolder subclass for displaying each item.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
        // layout called R.layout.menu_item for each item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);

        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position, Category model) {
        // Bind the Chat object to the ChatHolder
        // ...
    }
};
```

You can find more information here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaseui-for-realtime-database